# sql statement to Expression tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm wondering how one would translate a sql string to an expression tree.  Currently, in Linq to SQL, the expression tree is translated to a sql statement.  How does on go the other way?  How would you translate

```
select * from books where bookname like '%The%' and year > 2008
```

into an expression tree in c#?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this question. I am also in need of getting an expression tree from a sql string in c#

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/09/18/dynamic-string-based-queries-in-linq.aspx

**update**

The Entity framework has the Entity SQL language. Not sure if that is what you want though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521.aspx

Comment: Well...Sort of. Dynamic Linq allows you to specify your linq lambda expression arguments as strings, but you still have to specify the extension methods (.Select, .Where) of your linq statements directly.

Comment: it would be nice to not use dynamic linq but purely built from System.Linq.Expressions

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an easier way, but I wrote a lexer and parser for SQL expressions into a custom Abstract Syntax Tree (as I didn't know about .net's *Expression Trees* at the time) and I didn't really enjoy parsing SQL.

The syntax just is not very parse friendly, as order is different depending on context (e.g. the not in `NOT IN` vs. `IS NOT`), tokens are overloaded (the parenthesis for overriding the default operator precedence vs. parentheses for creating a list as in  `WHERE x IN (1, 2)`) and so forth.

Obviously using a parser generator rather than doing your own lexing and parsing would make things easier, but I don't know if there's anything more specific to SQL.

So, writing your own is definitely possible, albeit tedious.